# How do I map a complex object with Automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have several classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Customer_
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Article Article { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance:

```
Customer[] Customer = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName1",
        LastName = "LastName1",
        Product =  new Product()
        {
            Name = "Product1"
        }
    },
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName2",
        LastName = "LastName2",
        Product =  new Product()
        {
            Name = "Product2"
        }
    }
};
```

I want to map this instance to a `Customer_` object where `Customer.Product.Name` = `Customer_.Article.ArticleName`

I use Automapper:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Product, Article>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ArticleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));

});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var desti = mapper.Map<Customer[], Customer_[]>(Customer);
```

But I have a exception:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Customer -> Customer_
Xml_Test.Customer -> Xml_Test.Customer_

Destination path:
Customer_[][0]

Source value:
Xml_Test.Customer
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Just add `Customer` mapping: `cfg.CreateMap<Customer, Customer_>()` as said in error message.

Answer (score 4):

this should solve the problem -

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Product, Article>()
            .ForMember(a => a.ArticleName, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Name));
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, Customer_>()
            .ForMember(a => a.Article, b => b.ResolveUsing(c => c.Product));
```