# AutoMapper cannot map object inside object

Tags: c#, automapper

im trying to map ViewModels to Models. My models looks like this:

```
public class FinalsViewModel                   
{                                                  
    public FinalViewMode First { get; set; }                                          
    public FinalViewModel Second { get; set; }                                             
} 

public class Finals
{
    public Final First { get; set; }                                            
    public Final Second { get; set;  }
} 

// And Final:

public class FinalViewModel
{    
    public int Another { get; set; }
}  

public class Final
{    
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Another { get; set; }
}
```

I created mapping that looks like this:

```
CreateMap<FinalsViewModel, Finals>()
                .ForMember(src => src, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest) =>
                {
                    var list = new List<Final>();
                    if (src.First != null && src.First?.Another != null)
                        list.Add(new Final { Order = 1, Another = src.First.Another });
            
                    if (src.Second != null && src.Second?.Another != null)
                        list.Add(new Final { Order = 2, Another = src.Second.Another });
                   
            
                    var result = new Finals() // logic for mapping First = First, Second = Second etc;
            
                    return result;
                }));
```

Im getting error from this mapping:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.
```

My question is, how to rewrite this config to map object inside another object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I map a complex object with Automapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264049/how-do-i-map-a-complex-object-with-automapper)

Comment: Its not the same case. There isnt somehting like `.ResolveUsing` in AutoMapper api nowadeys

Comment: `FinalViewMode First`  is it a typo? or a different model compared to `FinalViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ForMember(source=>source)`;  AutoMapper default maps every property from source, and the  first parameter is an `Expression`, it design for get the member name ,  `x=>x.First`    will get the `First` and it's type.

You want to map `FinalsViewModel` to `Finals`. First you need to create a map of `FinalsViewModel` => `Finals`
then you need to create a map of `FinalViewMode` => `Final`

```
CreateMap<FinalsViewModel, Finals>();
CreateMap<FinalViewMode,Final>();

// you can also use `.ForMember()` to do more.
```